# Position an image on top of 2 backgrounds on html email

Tags: html, css, image, outlook, html-email

I'm having a trouble to position an image on top og 2 different backgrounds on html email.
web view is fine but for emails it's not. I need this code to preforme on all email clients.
here is the layout of what it supposed to look like, and how it is actually look like.
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jALyR.png)

it seems that the image can't get the neative margin to go on top of the other background.
here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            Margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            min-width: 100%;
            background-color: #F3F3F3;
        }
        table{
            border-spacing: 0;
        }
        td{
            padding: 0;
        }
        img{
            border: 0;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

        }


    </style>
    <!--[if mso]>
    <style>
        body{
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
            text-align: center!important;
            display: inline-block!important;
        }
        table{
            border-collapse: collapse!important;
        }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; background-color: #F3F3F3; padding-bottom: 20px; text-align: center;">
    <table style="background-color: white; color: #2E4A63; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; max-width: 600px; border-spacing: 0; padding-bottom: 20px;" width="100%" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="direction: ltr;" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <!-- Body Text -->
                        <td align="center" style="text-align: center;">
                            <h1 style="font-size: 30px; margin: 45px auto 20px auto; line-height: 32px;">
                                Highlight text
                            </h1>
                            <h3 style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: unset; line-height: 24px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto 37px auto;">
                                Paragraph text
                            </h3>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 50px;">

                            <a href="#" tabindex="-1" target="_blank" style="padding: 15px 55px; background-color: #ff3f4e; color: white; text-decoration: none; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; border-radius: 50px;">
                                <span style="color: white;">Button</span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- HERO 2 SECTION -->
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table style="background-image: url('urlbackground.png'); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 600px; max-width: 100%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <!-- TOP SECTION -->
                                    <td>
                                        <!-- Highlight text -->
                                        <h1 style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: unset; margin: 45px auto 15px auto; line-height: 32px; color: black;">
                                            some content
                                        </h1>
                                        <!-- Paragraph text -->
                                        <h3 style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: unset; line-height: 24px; text-align: center; margin: 0;color: black;">
                                            more content
                                        </h3>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 90px;">
                                        <a href="#" tabindex="-1" target="_blank" style="padding: 15px 60px; background-color: #16BBDF; color: white; text-decoration: none; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; border-radius: 50px;">
                                            <span style="color: white;">Button 2</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table style="background-image: url('urlbackground2.png'); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 600px; height: 250px; max-width: 100%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div style="margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 40px; color: black; text-align: left; padding: 0; width: 40%;">
                                            <h1 style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 1.2;">
                                                Highlight
                                            </h1>
                                            <h3 style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: unset;">
                                                some text
                                            </h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="image.png" alt="image" width="283" style="float: right; padding: 0;"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is going to be super tricky, and there are limitations, but check out https://codepen.io/matthieuSolente/pen/QWMLeZW for something 98% cross-email compatible (Gmail IMAP being notable one that will fallback to your current actual)

Comment: There's no simple answer sorry. This is the sort of job that I'd suggest asking a freelancer